# I just found my Euro Disney S.C.A share certificates

Tags: shares, selling, share-certificate

I've been trying yo find out how i can sell my Euro Disney S.C.A shares. I know Euro Disney brought back the shares in 2017

Comment: If the shares still have value, this is like selling shares of any other stock; hand them to a broker and say "sell these."